# Enterprise App not able to download on iPad

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have hosted my IOS App on company's server using Apple's enterprise development profile.

I was successfully able to download the App on my iPhone but not on my iPad.

It asks for Install nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: In xcode - Build Settings - Deployment section, there is a Target Device Family if that is iphone change that to iphone/ipad. give that a try

Comment: I have universal App. I have Deployment Target as 7.0 and I have 8.1 on my ipad. This App was working fine, It is almost 8 month old App. All of sudden it started giving this issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing the previous version on the iPad?

Comment: Yes i did that and tried to install it but nothing happens.. But same link works on my iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the iOS 8 loader for Enterprise installs. Unfortunately, the only way to circumvent this issue is to dynamically rename the bundle identifier in the plist for each request.

This will effectively install two instances of the application on your device but the legacy version will be deleted once installation has complete.

See the following link for further details:

[iOS 8 Enterprise Apps issue](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/248803?tstart=0)

The following link will also provide more details on how to implement such solutions:

[Enterprise catalog](http://www.xdumaine.com/creating-an-enterprise-app-catalog/)

Comment: This solved my problem.. Thanks so much.. There is bug in IOS 8

Answer (score 0):

Check for iOS version of Deployment Target in Xcode, maybe it's newer than the version on the iPad.

Comment: I have Deployment Target as 7.0 and have 8.1 on my ipad.